# Vectors Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boat is being pulled by two men.The stronger men exerts a force which is $(3/2)^{1/2}$ times that of the weaker man, and in the direction at angle $45^{\circ}$  north of east (i.e. $45^{\circ}$ counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis). Which direction must the weaker man pull to ensure the boat travels due east(positive $x$ direction)?

The answer given is $60^{\circ}$.

How to solve this type of question. Could someone give me some ideas to solve it?

Comment: Hint: Set the $y$-components of the vectors equal to each other and solve for the unknown angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the weaker man's force is $F$ at a direction $\theta$ south of east, then the resultant force on the boat is $(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}F \cos 45^\circ+F \cos \theta, \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}F \sin 45^\circ-F \sin \theta) = F (\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\cos 45^\circ+\cos \theta, \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \sin 45^\circ- \sin \theta)$.

In order for the boat to go in the $x$-direction, you need the $y$ resultant to be zero, ie, $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\sin 45^\circ =\sin \theta$, which gives $\sin \theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, or $\theta = 60^\circ$. The resultant force on the boat is $F(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2},0)$.

Comment: YES!!! I got it. Thank you very much bro

Answer (score 3):

Let the **magnitude** of the force exerted by the weaker person be $w$. Then the magnitude of the force exerted by the stronger one is $w\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Suppose that the weaker person will be exerting force in a direction $\theta$ degrees **South** of East. Make an informal sketch.

In order to make sure that the resultant force goes due East, the **northward** component of the force exerted by the stronger person must be cancelled by the **southward** component of the force exerted by the weakling.
It follows that
$$w\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\sin(45^\circ)=w\sin\theta.$$